# Python - Using Files From A Distribution

Tags: python-2.7

I have a group of files I wanted to create a distribution with. I followed the instructions found here: http://www.scotttorborg.com/python-packaging/minimal.html as well as here: http://guide.python-distribute.org/creation.html

I can create the distribution and can install it on my local system. When I open PyCharm, I can see the files in my External Libraries and I can see that the package is installed in the Project Interpreter settings, however I cannot use any of the files. When I try to do an import of those files they cannot be found.

As an aside when I go into Python27\Scripts all of my files are there, but the only thing in the Python27\Lib\site-packages is the egg-info file from the distribution I created.

Answer (score 0):

It was simply a matter of setting up things correctly and re-reading the instructions.